# innerHTML.replace works in jsfiddle but not in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have such problem:

I have a software which make an order confirmation in .html . I had to figure out how to delate some strings which I do not want to have on confirmation. Because of fact that I have not enough knowledge, I made something like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<div id="boxik"><div class="nazwa">SZ.*font>/, '');
</script>
```

Very unprofessional code to remove everything between some div, but it is enough for my solution. It works perfectly in jsfiddle, but not in any browser. Maybe I should load so jquery libary ? I am not sure it is why I am asking for help.

http://jsfiddle.net/LTfyH/79/

Comment: Where you have put the tag script  in the html?

Comment: Is your HTML dynamically loaded/constructed, as opposed to JSfiddle where it's hard coded?

Comment: Almost at the end like in jsfiddle

Comment: James, unfortunately I do not know. HTML is created by program and I have full access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the fact you're using the id `boxik` two times. You can only use a id once.

If you want to remove only one element you can use something like:

```
var el = document.getElementById('boxik');
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

If you want to remove multiple elements you can select them based on a class for example:

```
var elementsToRemove = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-me');
```

A example of both methods:
http://jsfiddle.net/LTfyH/81/

Notice that i added the class `remove-me` on two elements.

Comment: The problem is that each product have the same id/class (I can change ID into the class). I cannot choose the class that would be removed because everything has the same class. It is why I decided to use method which remove text between chosen words.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it in the document onload if you are using pure javascript:

```
(function () {
    document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<div id="boxik"><div class="nazwa">SZ.*font>/, '');
})();
```

Or if you are using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<div id="boxik"><div class="nazwa">SZ.*font>/, '');
});
```